# Error: HTTP Error: 400, Project 'projectname' is not a Firestore enabled project

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am getting this error : 
I think firebase setup is good but problem with deploy

```
=== Deploying to 'uiexpertonline'...

i  deploying storage, firestore, hosting
i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
✔  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  storage: uploading rules storage.rules...
i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
i  hosting: preparing dist directory for upload...
✔  hosting: 23 files uploaded successfully
✔  storage: released rules storage.rules to firebase.storage/uiexpertonline.appspot.com
✔  firestore: released rules firestore.rules to cloud.firestore

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/uiexpertonline/overview
Hosting URL: https://uiexpertonline.firebaseapp.com
Bhupinders-MacBook-Pro:ui bhupinder$
```

Comment: The output from the Firebase CLI that you're showing doesn't seem to be reporting any errors.  If you're seeing an error, could you edit your answer to show what's happening?

Comment: i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
these are the error and why i am not able to deploy the application like if you will visit this https://uiexpertonline.firebaseapp.com then you can see there is no data

Comment: Where and when do you get this error? "HTTP Error: 400, Project 'projectname' is not a Firestore enabled project"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing the firebase init that time you need to say No to override the index.html

Comment: why? and how to change this option after initiated

Answer (score -1):

Go to Firebase Console.
Select Database from left side navigation.
Click Get started.
The popup will show two options.
Select "Start in locked mode".
Click "Enable"
Try firebase deploy again.